# No matter what I do, django-admin.py is not found, even though it's in my path

Tags: python, django

I have added C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\bin to my path, I have started a new cmd session in Windows 7, but when I try to do 'python django-admin.py ...' it says there is no file django-admin.py.  When I type path, there is the full path to ...\django\bin. This is driving me nuts. Clearly it's there, but it's not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: So basically you want to know how to get django-admin.py to execute rather than being opened with another application (editor, IE, Firefox, etc).  In that case, ask on SuperUser.com.  I'm sure someone there can work it out for you.

Answer (score 5):

The python interpreter does *not* look everywhere on your path to find the script. It does look everywhere for imports, but not for scripts.

Try typing `django-admin.py`, just `django-admin.py` and not `python django-admin.py`, and it should work. Windows should find it on the path, then execute it as a python script.

OK,

If Windows doesn't run Python scripts (i.e. you have set your editor as the default python app), try: `python -m django-admin` or maybe `python -m django-admin.py`. The `-m` argument uses module mode, which checks the path.

Comment: +1 true (you could also type `python C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\bin\django-admin.py`, but that's inconvenient)

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, and yes it is not something I can lie with. The problem with just typing the script name is that Windows tried to launch the file with another app.

Answer (score 5):

I realize this is old, but came across the same issue.
On Windows, your path should include the following:

C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts

This is assuming python 2.7.3 is installed and django 1.4.3

Answer (score 4):

`python -mdjango-admin` looks like what you're looking for. `-m` tells Python to find a module on `sys.path` and run *that module* as "the main script" -- which seems exactly your goal!

Comment: I tried this -m command, but i get python does not recognize this module. I have also ensured that the path to the django-admin is provided in the system path in my environment variables. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

This python command will search syspath for the django module in question:

```
python -m django.bin.django-admin
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and python -mdjango-admin works. but i had to define PYTHONHOME & PYTHONPATH first